# How to change line curve labels in "vegan"

Tags: r, label, vegan, line-plot

I want to change the label of the two rarefaction curves and if possible also the color of each line.

```
rare_nano_sgl <- rarecurve(t(otu_table(physeqnanosingle)), xlab="sample size", ylab="number of species")

rare_nano_sgl + geom_text(title("Rarefaction Curve"))
```

enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

Would these work?

```
   label: Label rarefaction curves by rownames of ‘x’ (logical).

col, lty: plotting colour and line type, see ‘par’. Can be a vector of
          length ‘nrow(x)’, one per sample, and will be extended to
          such a length internally.
```

This is an extract from the documentation (?rarecurve). This says that `col` (colour) and `lty` (linetype) can be a vector that gives these parameters for each row. The function wants to use rownames as labels, and if you do not want to edit those, you need a bit acrobacy: draw the graph with `label=FALSE` and then add the labels with function `ordilabel` at coordinates `cbind(rowSums(x), specnumber(x))` (these coordinates you can find by peeking at the `rarecurve` code). This would draw curves for the BCI data and select the colour and label by the Habitat type:

```r
rarecurve(BCI, col=BCI.env$Habitat, label=FALSE)
ordilabel(cbind(rowSums(BCI), specnumber(BCI)), labels=BCI.env$Habitat)
legend("topleft", levels(BCI.env$Habitat), col=1:5, lty=1)
```

Comment: I have to be quite honest. I don't quite get it. (Note: I am absolute beginner). I removed the label with "label=FALSE". So far I get it. The rest unfortunately not.

Comment: I am working with a phyloseqobject. My goal is to name the labels myself. Inside the phyloseq object I have two samples.

Comment: Ok I managed to give different colors by `col <- c("darkred", "forestgreen")` and then assigning `col=col` inside the `rarecurve` function. I still don't have a solution for the labels though.

Comment: So you did not do like I wrote? 1) call `rarecurve` with `label=FALSE`, 2) add labels with `ordilabel(cbind(rowSums(<yourdata>), specnumber(<yourdata>)), labels=<yourlabels>)`.

Comment: I also noticed that you mix standard **R** graphics with **ggplot2** graphics: this won't work. You cannot plus **ggplot2** elements (`+ geom_text(...)`) to normal graphics. If you use `rarecurve`, you must use normal **R** graphics functions. For instance, `title()` will add the title to the graph. Alternatively, you can build up the graphics from the ground to use **ggplot2** idiom, but that is a Big Issue.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I thought I could use the ggplot arguments! When I try to call `title` to specify my axis-labels and the title I am left with this error `Error in seq.default(1, tot[i], by = step) : 'by' must be of length 1`. Thanks for your patience and time!